# Find all matching ids in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

We have two arrays of objects:

First:

```
const allUsers = [
  {
    id: 49,
    name: 'William'
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    name: 'Michael'
  },
]
```

Second:

```
const usersWithActivity = [
  {
    id: 49,
    name: 'William',
    last_activity: "2019-06-20T12:09:55.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    name: 'Michael',
    last_activity: "2020-02-20T11:08:50.000Z"
  }
]
```

[QUESTION]:

How can I return an array of all the users that were INACTIVE for the last 3 months? (William's)

Comment: Why not try something?

Comment: You can use `Array#filter` to iterate over `usersWithActivity` and exclude entries that don't match your condition (`last_activity < now - 3 months`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something

```
function monthDiff(dateFrom, dateTo) {
 return dateTo.getMonth() - dateFrom.getMonth() + 
   (12 * (dateTo.getFullYear() - dateFrom.getFullYear()))
}

const usersWithActivity = [
  {
    id: 49,
    name: 'William',
    last_activity: "2019-06-20T12:09:55.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    name: 'Michael',
    last_activity: "2020-02-20T11:08:50.000Z"
  }
]

const res = usersWithActivity.filter(user => (monthDiff( new Date(user.last_activity),new Date()) > 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const allUsers = [
  {
    id: 49,
    name: 'William'
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    name: 'Michael'
  },
];

const usersWithActivity = [
  {
    id: 49,
    name: 'William',
    last_activity: "2019-06-20T12:09:55.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 82,
    name: 'Michael',
    last_activity: "2020-02-20T11:08:50.000Z"
  }
];

function isInactiveSince(lastActivity, inactiveSince) {
  let la = new Date(lastActivity);
  let s = new Date().setMonth(inactiveSince)
  return la <= s
}

function play () {
    const all = [];
 usersWithActivity.map((ua, i) => {
      if(isInactiveSince(ua.last_activity, -3)) {
        const user = allUsers.find(u => u.id == ua.id)
        all.push(user);
      }
    })
    console.log(all)
}

play()
```